# Elasticsearch fails silently if document has mapping mismatch for a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a weird issue with Elasticsearch. My mapping specifies that a certain field is of type `long`. Now accidentally I was trying to index some documents which had `string` type for that field instead of `long`. I was getting no errors from Elasticsearch but the documents were never indexed. When I fixed the issue the documents were indexed just fine.

Example:

My mapping:

```
{
    "field1": {
        "type": "long"
    }
}
```

When I send this document it fails silently:

```
 {
     "field1": "this is a string"
 }
```

When I send this it works as expected:

```
 {
     "field1": 12345
 }
```

Is there a way to detect this kind of errors?

Comment: Can you share the response you are getting back from Elasticsearch when you have this silent index failure?

Comment: probably you have the [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-settings) flag set to true on global level . could you provide  an example document  that you indexed which caused it to fail silently, also the version of elasticsearch.

Comment: See my updated question for an example. I think the flag you just mentioned might be what I was looking for. The only issue is that this would just ignore the malformed field but still index the rest of the doc which is not good for me since that field is required. I'd like it to fail and return an error if it tries to index a malformed field. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-settings)  string to false. It would not index the  document if it is malformed but throws an exception. At least in elasticsearch 1.6.0.

Example:

```
put test

put test/test/_mapping 
{
    "properties" : {
        "title" : {"type" : "string"},
        "data" : {"type": "long" ,"ignore_malformed":false}

    }
}

put test/test/1
{
    "data" : "1",
    "title" : "valid coerce string to number"
}

put test/test/2
{
    "data" : "hello",
    "title" : "invalid number"
}

#Failed Response
{
   "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse [data]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"hello\"]; ",
   "status": 400
}

Query with Get fails

get test/test/2


{
   "_index": "test",
   "_type": "test",
   "_id": "2",
   "found": false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your mapping looks similar to this:

```
{
    "long_field": {
        "type": "long"
    }
}
```

If that's the case, you can set the `coerce` flag to `false` as it is [`true` by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#number) and will always try to convert strings to numbers and truncate fractions for integers.

```
{
    "long_field": {
        "type": "long",
        "coerce": false
    }
}
```

If you do this, the next time you try to index a long field as a string, ES will tell you this:

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [long_field]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Long value passed as String];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes my mapping specifies a long type (see my updated question) but I would like to index strings which cannot be converted to integers. So I don't think this would work in this case but it's useful for other cases. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure: "which cannot" or "which can"? The way I understand is that you want `"123"` (number as string) and `123` (number as long) to succeed, but `"not a number"` (bad string) to fail. Is that correct?

Comment: I just want the field to accept strings without coercing them.