# Elasticsearch default behavior for mismatch (bad) type

Tags: elasticsearch

When indexing an ip, I may have an ipv6 type come through. Trying my best at mapping-foo (until they add support for ipv6), I am trying to do something like this:

```
"ip" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "norms" : {
              "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
            "ipV4" : { "type":"ip", "store":true}
        }
  }
```

But I don't have it all the way. What I want is the following:

1. Store the ip field as a string always
2. If its an ipV4 string, store it that way, but if its not, don't throw an error and store a default value instead.

What do I need to change/add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped answer my question:

[Elasticsearch fails silently if document has mapping mismatch for a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224335/elasticsearch-fails-silently-if-document-has-mapping-mismatch-for-a-field?rq=1)

it makes my response look more like this:

```
"ip" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "norms" : {
              "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
            "ipV4" : { 
                 "type":"ip", 
                 "store":true, 
                 "ignore_malformed":true, 
                 "null_value":"255.255.255.255"
            }
        }
      }
```

Im going to try before marking this as correct